# Rain Framework on Ubuntu server on Amazon

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to install Rain framework on Ubuntu server on Amazon for my mobile application API. It runs fine on my Windows PC with XAMPP server, but when I put this to main server this shows the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RainTpl_Exception' with message 'Cache directory cache/doesn't have write permission. Set write permission or set RAINTPL_CHECK_TEMPLATE_UPDATE to false. More details on http://www.raintpl.com/Documentation/Documentation-for-PHP-developers/Configuration/' in /var/www/html/pidentity/api/system/library/View/rain.tpl.class.php:312

Stack trace:

```
#0./var/www/html/pidentity/api/system/library/View/rain.tpl.class.php(266): RainTPL->compileFile('content', 'content/', 'app/views/conte...', 'cache/', 'cache/content.9...') 
#1./var/www/html/pidentity/api/system/library/View/rain.tpl.class.php(154): RainTPL->check_template('content/content') 
#2./var/www/html/pidentity/api/system/library/View/Raintpl_View.php(30): RainTPL->draw('content/content', false) 
#3./var/www/html/pidentity/api/system/library/View.php(62): Raintpl_view->draw('content/content', false) 
#4./var/www/html/pidentity/api/app/controllers/content/content.php(15): View->draw('content/content') 
#5.[internal function]: Content_Controller->inde in /var/www/html/pidentity/api/system/library/View/rain.tpl.class.php on line 312
```

Answer (score 2):

You must set the correct write permission in the cache folder.

You can do that by checking what user and group is running your web server (apache, nginx or other), to do that you can run:

```
$ ps aux | grep apache (or nginx)
```

then you want to set the user, the group and the permissions:

```
$ chown -R [username] ./cache
$ chgrp -R [groupname] ./cache
$ chmod -R 755 ./cache
```